# Getting custom file property in file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there is a way to get custom properties in file that comes from javascript.

Like this:

[image]

This is my file object that goes to server with an ajax request.

When when I print $_FILES in server side I'm only getting default values:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you need these files information, you must send them from javascript to your server and your PHP script have to manage them.

Comment: use `exif_read_data('tmp name file path here', 'IFD0')` to get the headers for each file

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how this informations are send to PHP.
The superglobal $_FILE only prints form uploaded file informations.

Try to print $_POST and see what you get https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php